# Можно ли поставить здесь запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сравнительный-оборот, сравнение, оборот-с-как

...сможет действовать(,) как настоящий преступник, с холодной головой...

Answer (score 1):

**...сможет действовать, как настоящий преступник, с холодной головой...**

Запятая **ставится**, потому что оборот *как настоящий преступник* обозначает уподобление (подобно настоящему преступнику) и, следовательно, является сравнительным оборотом, а сравнительные обороты требуют обособления с двух сторон.

Answer (score 0):

Этот вопрос не так прост, как может показаться.  Здесь опять же требуется внимание к автору – ведь скорее всего, он знает, как обособляются сравнительные обороты.
Поэтому дело не в том, как обособлять оборот, а в том, как точнее определить грамматику и значение высказывания. Я здесь вижу **два варианта:**

(1) **сравнение** с преступником (как будто):   *…сможет действовать, **как настоящий преступник,** с холодной головой...*

(2) **Однородные** обстоятельства, раскрытие одной темы: *…сможет действовать **как настоящий престУпник**, с холодной головОй...*

Выбор за автором.

При постановке запятой мы имеем **попутное сравнение и вставочную интонацию,** поэтому основной смысл передает сочетание "с холодной головой."

Во втором варианте оба обстоятельства **равноправны,** они оба выделены ударением. Получается развитие темы и в какой-то мере усиление значения.